# Getting textBox value of checked row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I am having some problem for getting the text from textbox in a row which the checkbox was marked check in gridview. When button on click, it supposed to get the checked row index for prodID and the quantity which is the text from textbox:

```
protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string quantity = "" , prodID = "";
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                    if (cb.Checked)
                    {
                        //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames for selected row index
                        prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                        var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                        if (tbQuantity != null)
                        {
                            quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                        }
                        tempList.Add(prodID);
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
        {    
            //Testing
            lblTest.Text += tempList[i] + " " + quantity;
        }
    }
```

Let's say I got prodID 1 with 50 units, prodID 2 with 77 units, prodID 3 with 90 units. When I loop thru the tempList, this is the result which I supposed to get:

```
1 50units, 2 77units, 390units
```

However, the codes does not get the quantity from the textbox for each product independently. Here is the result which I get:

```
1 90units, 2 90units, 3 90units
```

It just simply get the quantity of last product in the list. I wonder is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Edited Portion:

```
 foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
        {
            packagesNeeded = 1;
            unitQty = prodPackBLL.getUnitQtySPU(tempList[key]);
            lblTest.Text += key + " " + tempList[key];
            if (Convert.ToInt32(quantity) < (packagesNeeded * unitQty))
            {
                //Pop up message
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "alert(\"Insufficient storage\");", true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you select check boxes in multiple row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pair each `prodID` with its corresponding `quantity`. Try this code:

```
protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string quantity = "", prodID = "";
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
            GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames for selected row index
                    prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                    var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                    if (tbQuantity != null)
                    {
                        quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                    }
                    tempList.Add(prodID, quantity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
    {
        packagesNeeded = 1;
        unitQty = prodPackBLL.getUnitQtySPU(key);
        lblTest.Text += key + " " + tempList[key];
        if (Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key]) < (packagesNeeded * unitQty))
        {
            //Pop up message
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "alert(\"Insufficient storage\");", true);
        }
    } 
}
```

Based on your examples above, `tempList["1"]` will produce `"50"`, `tempList["2"]` will produce `"77"`, and `tempList["3"]` will produce `"90"`.

Comment: Can you help me check the edited portion? When I try to access the quantity, it gives me an error message of Input string was in incorrect format. Why is it so?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you have to convert tempList[key] instead of quantity variable. You also have to validate and make sure that the textboxes should only contain integer value.

Comment: I thought the tempList[key] contain prodID and quantity? How the program know which one to compare to? And hmm, it does not works. The error message is still the same

Comment: Just edited my answer again and added some explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Oh ya, I concatenate my quantity when retrieving it. Sorry my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in GV.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value) == true)
                //here you get the rowcell value :
                string val = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //If you want to convert to a textbox :
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)item.Cells[1].Value;
        }
```

where GV is the gridview Id
and checkbox is the 0 column and the value you might want to get is the 1 column

Comment: I managed to get the checked row index but just not the textbox value along with it. Your Cells[1] means the textBox column?

Comment: Or should I add another list to store the quantity just like the one I did for prodID?

Comment: cells[i] is the i th column cell in current row

Comment: but it's not TextBox. how should convert it to TextBox?

Comment: I edited my answear to show you how to convert the cell to textbox

Answer (score 1):

It is because you keep overriding variable "quantity" for each row you have the checkbox selected. If you want to store multiple values you need to use `List<string>` to store the quantities for each row where the checkbox is selected.

Something like below. Note: I haven't tested the code.

```
protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> quantity = new List<string>(); 
    prodID = "";
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
            GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames for selected row index
                    prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                    var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                    if (tbQuantity != null)
                    {
                        quantity.Add(tbQuantity.Text);
                    }
                    tempList.Add(prodID);
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
    {    
        //Testing
        lblTest.Text += tempList[i] + " " + quantity[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: So that means I need a nested for-loop to get both prodID and quantity? Can you show me some examples?

Comment: Oh ya I shouldn't put the nested loop because it gives me an error message of index out of bound exception. Thanks it works!

Comment: Glad it works.... You can also use the Dictionary as @ekad mentioned... Its a better solution...

Comment: However, when I try to compare the quantity value, it told me that input string was not in correct format although I already try this: Convert.ToInt32(quantity). Can you help me check the edited portion and help me point out what went wrong?

Comment: Are you using Dictionary as @ekad mentioned or my solution?

Comment: The dictionary one. Is it because sometimes when getting text from textbox and do some conversion, the conversion does not went properly because I have found some solutions on int.TryParse() but I have no idea on how to fit it into my code